# Did Brook Taylor develop his formula also in many variables by himself?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, math-history

I was wondering whether Brook Taylor was also familiar with analysis in many variables at that time. I found no information about it online.
Greetings Eu2718

Comment: I've looked at this briefly (on [MacTutor](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Taylor.html) mostly) and there is no indication that Taylor, or anybody else at the time for that matter, was considering (expressions for) functions of multiple variables at all.

Comment: Hello Marc. This is exactly what I was thinking, but why do we then call it this way in such a case?

Answer (score 2):

After some googling, I believe the first one who wrote down the Taylor-like expansion for **two-variable functions** is sure **Joseph-Louis Lagrange**. Also my hunch was him for his contributions in Lagrange multipliers and calculus of variations.

In his book *Théorie des fonctions analytiques* [page 92](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-86263&I=105&M=tdm), he considered the function $f(x+i,y+o)$, and expanded it fixing $i$ and $o$ respectively. Then in page 93 he reached the following expansion:

> $$
> f(x+i,y+o) =  f(x,y)+if'(x,y)+of_{\prime}(x,y) 
> \\
> + \frac{i^2}{2}f''(x,y) + io f'_{\prime}(x,y)+ \frac{o^2}{2}f_{\prime\prime}(x,y) + \frac{i^3}{2\cdot 3} f'''(x,y) 
> \\
> + \frac{i^2o}{2} f''_{\prime}(x,y) + \frac{io^2}{2} f'_{\prime\prime}(x,y) +  \frac{o^3}{2\cdot 3} f_{\prime\prime\prime}(x,y) + \& c. 
> $$

Translating into modern mathematical notation, it is just 
$$
f(x+\delta x, y+\delta y) = f(x,y) + f_x(x,y) \delta x + f_y(x,y)\delta y
\\
+ \frac{1}{2!}f_{xx}(x,y)  (\delta x) ^2 +f_{xy}(x,y) \delta x\delta y  + \frac{1}{2!}f_{yy}(x,y)  (\delta y) ^2
+ \frac{1}{3!} f_{xxx}(x,y) (\delta x) ^3
\\
+ \frac{1}{2} f_{xxy}(x,y) (\delta x) ^2 \delta y+ \frac{1}{2} f_{xyy}(x,y)  \delta x   (\delta y)^2 +  \frac{1}{3!} f_{yyy}(x,y) (\delta y)^3 + 
\text{Error term}.$$

My French is almost amateur, but it seems Lagrange didn't mention the order of partial derivatives in his notation.

My investigation started with the quote in the entry [Taylor's theorem of wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem):

> Taylor's theorem is named after the mathematician Brook Taylor, who stated a version of it in 1712. Yet, an explicit expression of the error was provided much later on by Joseph-Louis Lagrange.